# Starting  a thread in the code

Tags: android, multithreading

How can I start the thread in this code? Where and how to start the thread activity because my application stops when it goes to this section of code.

```
public class Lesson_p extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

MediaPlayer p, p_sound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lesson_p);
    p = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p);
    p_sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p_sound);

    View p = findViewById(R.id.imageButton_p);
    p.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);

    View p_sound = findViewById(R.id.imageButton_pp);
    p_sound.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);

    Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_bckp);
    back.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_nxtp);
    next.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageButton_p:
            p.start();
            break;

        case R.id.imageButton_pp:
            p_sound.start();
            break;

        case R.id.button_bckp:
            Intent back = new Intent(this, Example_n.class);
            startActivity(back);
            break;

        case R.id.button_nxtp:
            Intent next = new Intent(this, Example_p.class);
            startActivity(next);
            break;

        }


}
//@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    p.release();
    p_sound.release();
}

}
```

Comment: You said your application stops when it gets to that section of code, yet you provide 3 functions. Which function is it stopping in?

Comment: it's stop in the button_nxtp function

Comment: That is because you are starting a new activity so your music player stops, and your new activity called Example_p starts.

Comment: why is this so happen? because the other activity use this structure of codes is working fine, , but when it comes in this code the application will stop.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this class

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

This is a useful class if you want to do something in the background, but remember threads cannot interact with elements in the main UI thread directly.

Answer (score 0):

You said it stops in the `button_nxtp` function (which isn't a function, it's just a certain case in a switch).

Looks like you're creating and starting an Intent for an `Example_p` activity. Step through the `onCreate()` and `onStart()` methods of your `Example_p` class using the debugger and you should be able to find your error.

Comment: Lunch time out has expired, giving up wake lock!. Activity timeout for historyrecord. . this the error message that comes from the logcat. .